# connectNulls:false functionality with no data

Tags: highcharts

I have an area chart (and a percent-area chart) that uses timeseries data for the x-axis. The timeseries is missing some data points and I would like the functionality to be that of connectNulls:false.

Is there another HighCharts option or a way to extend HighCharts to add an option for this functionality?

I have looked at the docs and browsed the questions here on StackOverflow and Googled for it, but the solution that I have found is to use connectNulls:false and to insert NULL values for the missing data points, but inserting the missing data points with null values would be cumbersome in my situation and I would have to replicate it in a few places.

I would imagine that it would be possible since in the instances that there is a missing data point, HighCharts will maintain the x-axis spacing. All I would want is addition to noticing the missing data point and inserting the appropriate spacing to also use a y-axis value of 0/inset a NULL/the equivalent.

Thank you all for your time and assistance.

Comment: But how would Highcharts know that you are missing some of points if you don't set them directly? For example, you have two points: at 10:23am and then 11.34am - how many missing points is there? Anyway, to use `connectNulls` option, you need to feed chart data with null points.

Comment: Yes, the chart has no way to know what you consider 'missing' in any given situation.  You will need to preprocess the data in order to tell it. You should be able to create a function or class to do this, and then you can use the same code anywhere without re-writing each time.

Comment: @Pawel Fus, your mention of 10:23 and 11:34 has shed some light on my confusion because the times you chose are random and illustrates how HighCharts renders the data. I have had a bit of tunnel vision because all of my data is at regular intervals and I inadvertently made some assumptions about how the data is rendered. Thank you for opening my eyes a bit.